# Elasticsearch search frontend demo

Tags: user-interface, search, elasticsearch, frontend, demo

i'm searching for working search ui demo or tutorial for building search UI/Frontend. At best for php or js.
I never builded a elasticsearch application, but I already made projects with lucene, solr, epoq and google search.

Already searched on inet but most example are very simple and incomplete.
Examples:
github.com/scotchfield/elasticsearch-react-example/
github.com/spalger/elasticsearch-angular-example

There also API for PHP and JS

www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html
www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_quickstart.html

What a example should contain (from my view)
* Basic Search Field
* Filter based on es fields index
* Resultview
* Filter interaction with results
* Paging

I was thinking something like this is already exits, but found no matching   one. I think better ask, before invest time in creating.

Thanks in Advance

densanki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this live demo interesting:
http://demo.searchkit.co/imdb

Answer (score 2):

If you already know ElasticSearch query syntax and some basic concepts like aggregations you may test all that on https://demo.elastic.co/app/kibana. But again, this would require some basic knowledge of Elastic stack.

Otherwise if you want just touch/try most common Elasticsearch features without going into implementations details then you may check [these 3 demos](http://searchkit.co/demos) for 3rd party SearchKit UI component.

Answer (score 2):

There's also Elastic UI that you might be interested in: https://elastic.github.io/eui/#/

If you want something ready-made for the time-series use-case, you might want to check [Sematext Cloud](https://sematext.com/cloud/). There's a simpler UI than Kibana there, but there's [API access](https://sematext.com/docs/logs/search-through-the-elasticsearch-api/), too, so you can develop your own.